# Reduce any spanning list to a finite spanning list

Tags: vector-spaces

$F$ is a field and $V$ is an finitely generated $F$ vector space. Show that any spanning set of $V$ can be reduced to a finite spanning set.

My ideas are that because $V$ is finitely generated, $V$ has a finitely generating system (spanning system). This generating system can then be reduced to a Basis $B$ of $V$. Let $U$ be the spanning set of $V$ which is possibly infinitely large. Since every element of $U$ is in $V$ I can write every element as a linear combination of my basis vectors in $B$. But this does not make $V$ any less of size, right?

Sorry for the possibly bad english translation. I hope it is clear what I mean.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

$V(F) $ is finitely generated vector space.

Suppose, $S\subset V$ finite set of vectors and $\langle S\rangle =V$

Then $S$ span the whole space $V$

And any spanning set can be reduced to a basis by deleting the dependent vectors.

In other words, basis is a minimal spanning set, hence basis $B\subseteq S$ and then $B$ will be finite.

Comment: Yes but I think I habe to prove this for $S$ being possible infinitetely big.

Comment: You have asked to prove about finitely generated vector space. A vector space $V$  is said to be finitely generated if there exists a finite set $  S $ such that $ Span (S) = V  $.And it's is not difficult to prove a spanning set can be reduced to a basis , it's called deletion theorem for finite dimensional vector space.

Comment: Yes but this is not the question. The question is the following: One span is finite dimensional and generates $V$ (because it's finitely generated) and another one $U$ which has infinite many elements. Now I want to show that $U$ can be reduced to a finite span of $V$